# Import the data into view

Tags: views

I want to import data from excel to created view how can I do this? using what module I can achieve? I found some user import tutorial but in views how to import the data?

Your suggestions are valuable thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can never import to created view. View is to create, manage, and display lists of content. So first you have to import the data from excel sheet to the content type which you are using into your view as a **content type filter**.

To import the data, install [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module.

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple
>   database records.